# Remove empty space around absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have inserted a div after a second paragraph in Wordpress post, but I would like to remove empty space on the right side which is visible in the picture. How can I do it?

Code for div is

```
max-width: 350px;
position: relative;
left: -100px;
float: left;
margin: 30px 0;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change max-width? Insert the code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `position: relative; left: 100px;` combo for this effect.  Positioning relative will preserve the space in the DOM where the element was originally.  Instead, use a negative right margin.  That will allow he content to the right of the element to collapse left.

```
max-width: 350px;
float: left;
margin: 30px 0 30px -100px;  /* maybe change this to
                                30px 15px 30px -100px
                                just to add a little
                                spacing. */
```

Here's a quick demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm0oyebx/